# How to create a regex consisting of specific characters occupying a specific order, but having different length

Tags: regex

Let us say we have the word **residence**. It could be matched by the following regular expression in js:

```
residence.match( new RegExp(/[residence]{4,9}/, 'i' ) )
```

This is fine, but there is a problem for me:
All the letters are interchangeable. This expression could match also:

```
ceresiden, denceresid, ence etc...
```

I would like to have  the order of the characters preserved. The regex should match strings like:

```
resid sidence ience rednce etc..
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use lookahead to test the valid strings and then test the length:

```js
var test = [
    'ceresiden',
    'denceresid',
    'ence',
    'res',
    'den',
    'resid',
    'sidence',
    'ience',
    'rednce',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a + ' :' + a.match(/^(?=r?e?s?i?d?e?n?c?e?$).{4,9}$/);
}));
```

Comment: Ah, clever use of lookaheads! I like this solution better than the one I posted! :D

Answer (score 1):

So you want them in the same order, but possibly with any number of characters removed? Then just make each character optional: `/(r?e?s?i?d?e?n?c?e?){4,9}/i`

Note: this regex, and the one you posted, will not match any of the strings you specified, because of the `{4,9}` quantifier. A string matching the pattern must including substrings matching the "residence"-optional pattern at least 4 times in a row (without spaces, etc.) for it to match.

Comment: Thank's a lot!!! I was just trying to do it in the same manner as you, but had made an error in the brackets - square in stead of curly

Comment: And how can we make it match strings which are between 4 to 9 characters long?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure you can do it directly in the regex. Matching a character group while preserving relative order *and* limiting the length is at best quite difficult, at worse impossible. I'd recommend you filter out the invalid lengths after matching everything. (In other words, run the match to get all strings of any length, then filter out with code the ones that are >9 or <4 characters long.)